# Function.prototype.apply: Arguments list has wrong type

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

`The error in the title of the post came from jQuery version 1.10.2, line 637`
I've got a modal that pops up on a button click with some textboxes and when a button inside the modal is clicked, the information that's in the text boxes is added to a database via AJAX.  In order to make the page a little more user-friendly I added a setTimeout function to pause the hiding of the modal so the user can see a verification message that the data was added to the database.  Block 1 of my code adds the record to the database, but the setTimeout call doesn't work right:

```
 function insert(data) {
                data = JSON.stringify(data);
                $.ajax({
                    type: "POST",
                    url: "../Service.asmx/InsertPerson",
                    dataType: "json",
                    contentType: "application/json",
                    data: data,
                    //record gets added to the database
                    //something about the setTimeout function 
                    //that gives the error in the title
                    success: function () {
                        console.log('success before setTimeout');
                        var successMessage = $('<div>').text('Successfully added to the database...').css('color', 'green');
                        $('.modal-body').append(successMessage);
                        //*******this function doesn't run
                        window.setTimeout(function () {
                            $('#contact').modal('hide');
                            $('.modal-body input').each(function () {
                                $(this).val('');
                            }, 1000);
                        });
                    }
                });
            }
```

I fixed it using the code:
(the success function is what we need to pay attention to here)

```
function insert(data) {
                data = JSON.stringify(data);
                $.ajax({
                    type: "POST",
                    url: "../Service.asmx/InsertPerson",
                    dataType: "json",
                    contentType: "application/json",
                    data: data,
                    //record gets added to the database
                    success: function () {
                        console.log('success before setTimeout');
                        var successMessage = $('<div>').text('Successfully added to the database...').css('color', 'green');
                        $('.modal-body').append(successMessage);
                        window.setTimeout(function () {
                            $('.modal-body input').each(function () {
                                $(this).val('');
                            });
                            $('#contact').modal('hide');
                        }, 1000);

                    }
                });
            }
```

I see that I in the first block I didn't close the `each` function, and I fixed that in the second block and that's why it works, but for future reference, what does this error really MEAN in this context?

Comment: I see no `.apply` anywhere in your code.

Comment: @FritsvanCampen that error came from jQuery.

Comment: @FritsvanCampen in version 1.10.2 of jQuery on line 637

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It means that you left off the second argument to `setTimeout` and instead passed it as the second argument to `.each()`.

*edit* — it looks like jQuery is picking up the argument (that `1000`) and trying to pass it through to its internal `each` implementation. The `.apply()` function expects it to be an array.

Comment: Thanks, should have mentioned that the error was coming from jQuery.